# Onclick get division

Tags: html-lists

i am trying to to get div with onclick event on li but it dosen't work so give useful answer.
my code is as follows:

```
<script>
 function myFunction(){
 var x=document.get.ElementById('demo'){
 if(x.style.display==='none'){
 x.style.display='block';
 }
 else{
 x.style.display='none';
}
}
</script>
```

html part is as follows

```
<ul>
<li onclick="myFunction()"> THIS IS DEMO</li>
 </ul>
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script>
 function myFunction(){
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0];
    if(x.style.display==='none'){
       x.style.display='block';
    }else{
       x.style.display='none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <ul>
<li onclick="myFunction()"> THIS IS DEMO</li>
 </ul>
<div class="demo">Demo</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You had to use "getElementsByClassName", not "getElementById". When you get element by className, it returns an array, so you have to add [0] at the end.